# How to rename dimnames default format (e.g. dimnames[[3]]) into a specific label (e.g. dimnames$time)

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, matrix, multidimensional-array

so I was trying to convert a data frame to a multidimensional matrix and I was able to do so. My only problem now is labelling them.

So far, I have four attributes for each dimnames but I cannot rename them. The tutorials I have seen online all want me to list down name per column, like this:

```
dimnames(dfa)[[2]] <-c("col_1", "col_2", "col_3)
```

but I don't need several names for column or row, all I need is one general label.

Basically, what I have now is this:
[image: Current file]

But what I need are these labels after the $ sign [image: Labels I want]

So in the end, my file looks like this: [image]

But I want labels (time, ID, factor_level,chan) like this: [image]

I tried the following codes to rename the rows, didn't work

```
rownames(dfa) <-"factor_level"

dimnames(dfa) [[1]] <- c("factor_level")
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

We need `names`

```
names(dimnames(dfa))[1] <- 'factor_level'
```

-outut

```
> dfa
, , 1, 1

            NA
factor_level col_1 col_2 col_3
       row_1     7     7     8
       row_2     3     2     6
       row_3     8     3     9

, , 2, 1

            NA
factor_level col_1 col_2 col_3
       row_1     4     7     8
       row_2     9     8     1
       row_3     8     1     5

, , 3, 1

...
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
dfa <- array(sample(1:9, size = 3 * 3 * 3 * 2, replace = TRUE), 
      dim = c(3, 3, 3, 2))
dimnames(dfa)[[2]] <- c("col_1", "col_2", "col_3")
dimnames(dfa)[[1]] <- c("row_1", "row_2", "row_3")
```